# Error Mapping Shared Libraries with Eclipse CDT and GDB

Tags: eclipse, gdb, eclipse-cdt, gdbserver

I'm trying to debug a program using a Ubuntu 12.04 host and an ARM client with Eclipse Kepler, CDT, and GDB. The host is running GDB 7.4 and the client 7.0.1.

In my .gdbinit file I `set sysroot /usr/local/arm-none-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/`

However, when I try to debug I get the following error:

```
Warning: Unable to find dynamic linker breakpoint function.
GDB will be unable to debug shared library initializers
and track explicitly loaded dynamic code.

The target endianness is set automatically (currently little endian)

Error while mapping shared library sections:
/usr//lib/libstdc++.so.6: No such file or directory. 

Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/libm.so.6: No such file or directory.

Warning: .dynamic section for "/usr/local/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/arm-none-linux-gnueabi/lib/libgcc_s.so.1" is not at the expected address (wrong library or version mismatch?)

Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/libc.so.6: No such file or directyory.

Error while mapping shared library sections:
/lib/ld-linux.so.3: No such file or directory.
```

I've searched this problem to death and can't seem to resolve it. Any answers would be most appreciated!